# why is find on my bind mount not working

Tags: lubuntu, find

I'm running lubuntu 20.04.

In /etc/fstab I mount my Debian-home filesystem and from that a bind mount for an folder.

```
cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=a19641aa-75ea-4815-b7c3-ce4c0a3cd0c9 /              ext4    defaults,discard 0 1
UUID=3bbf1ad8-b0d0-464e-a73b-9337e16d95d0 /home          ext4    defaults   0 2
UUID=927f38a0-c962-47de-9361-f1730032704e swap           swap    defaults   0 2
# Debian-home einbinden  # my debian $HOME filesystem
UUID=1ebf0f02-cdd8-44d9-80f9-7078de79e191  /media/debian-home-partition  ext4 user,auto    0       2
# einzelne Ordner einbinden von debian-home # folder with Videos
/media/debian-home-partition/alex/jd2  /home/alex/jd2   none  bind,defaults                 0       0

tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

The user in debian and ubuntu are the same name and (id/gid). I can mv or cp files from ubuntu $HOME to bind folder.

but somehow find is not working.

```
find jd2/downloads/ -name Xemnas
```

Nothing.

but

```
ls -al jd2/downloads/ | grep -i xemnas
-rw-rw-r--   1 alex alex 305670178 Dez 31 16:18 Kingdom Hearts 3 ReMind - Roxas, Axel, Xion vs Xemnas Boss Fight (PS4 Pro) (4K) (60FPS)-AQofRl7z2u8.mp4
```

try a little bit debug

```
LANG=C
alex@Guilmon:~$ find -D tree jd2/downloads/ -name xemnas
Predicate List:
[(] [-name] [)] [-a] [-print] 
Eval Tree:
pred=[-a] type=bi_op prec=and cost=Unknown est_success_rate=0,1000 no side effects 
left:
    pred=[-name xemnas] type=primary prec=no cost=Unknown est_success_rate=0,1000 no side effects 
    no children.
right:
    pred=[-print] type=primary prec=no cost=Unknown est_success_rate=1,000 side effects 
    no children.
Normalized Eval Tree:
pred=[-a] type=bi_op prec=and cost=Nothing est_success_rate=0,1000 no side effects 
left:
    pred=[-a] type=bi_op prec=and cost=Nothing est_success_rate=0,1000 no side effects 
    no left.
    right:
        pred=[-name xemnas] type=primary prec=no cost=Nothing est_success_rate=0,1000 no side effects 
        no children.
right:
    pred=[-print] type=primary prec=no cost=Nothing est_success_rate=1,000 side effects 
    no children.
Optimized Eval Tree:
pred=[-a] type=bi_op prec=and cost=Nothing est_success_rate=0,1000 no side effects 
left:
    pred=[-a] type=bi_op prec=and cost=Nothing est_success_rate=0,1000 no side effects 
    no left.
    right:
        pred=[-name xemnas] type=primary prec=no cost=Nothing est_success_rate=0,1000 no side effects 
        no children.
right:
    pred=[-print] type=primary prec=no cost=Nothing est_success_rate=1,000 side effects 
    no children.
Optimized command line:
-name xemnas [est success rate 0,1] -a [est success rate 0,1] -print [est success rate 1]
```

Is my bind mount not right? Or did I oversee something by my find command?

Comment: `-name xemnas` will only match files whose names are exactly `xemnas` - to be equivalent to your `ls ... | grep -i xemnas` command you would need `-iname '*xemnas*'`

Comment: @steeldriver  I'l triede `-iname xemnas`  also not working but yours work. `find jd2/downloads/ -iname '*xemnas*'
jd2/downloads/Kingdom Hearts 3 ReMind - Roxas, Axel, Xion vs Xemnas Boss Fight (PS4 Pro) (4K) (60FPS)-AQofRl7z2u8.mp4` thanks  Make please an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
find <path> -name xemnas
```

will only match files whose names are exactly `xemnas` - to be equivalent to your `ls ... | grep -i xemnas` command you would need

```
find <path> -iname '*xemnas*'
```

where the `*`s are glob wildcards matching zero or more leading / trailing characters and `-iname` makes the match case-insensitive. For your particular case, you could also make just the initial X case insensitive using `-name '*[Xx]emnas*'`